# Typescript: Type-mapped type cannot be indexed with original type

Tags: typescript, type-mapping

I am writing a class that is instantiated that has a method whose return type is an object with the keys from the generic type inferred by the compiler.  I am running into issues with the following code snippet as the compiler tells me that the generic type `U` cannot be indexed by type `T` -- which I believe is incorrect due to the fact that `U` is type-mapped using `T`, therefore T will always be able to index an object of type `U`.  Is there a way of affirming to the compiler that this is the case?

Minimal snippet:

```js
class DynamicReturnFormat<T extends string, U = { [ key in T ]: string }> {
  constructor(private keys: T[]) {}

  public returnObject(): U {
    const obj = {} as U;

    for (const key of this.keys) {
      obj[key] = "test";
      // error TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'U'.
    }

    return obj;
  }
}
```

As per Rich N.'s answer, this class will be used as follows:

```js
declare const input: Buffer;

const fmt = ["length", "packetID", ...];
const handshakeParser = new DataParser(fmt);

const decodedObject = handshakeParser.decode(input);
```

For context: `DynamicReturnFormat` is `DataParser` and `returnObject` is `decode`.  I would like `decodedObject` to have a non-"one size fits all" type that only includes the properties that were passed into the class instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear how you want this to be used, but I'm guessing you want to do something like:

```
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const drf = new DynamicReturnFormat(keys);
const result = drf.returnObject();
```

Then result should be {a: "test", b: "test", c: "test" }?

If so, the code below works.  I've had to take out the second generic variable U, and use a Partial as {} is not assignable to type {[key in T]: string}:

```
class DynamicReturnFormat<T extends string> {
    constructor(private keys: T[]) { }

    public returnObject(): { [key in T]: string } {
        const obj: Partial<{ [key in T]: string }>= {};

        for (const key of this.keys) {
            obj[key] = "test";
        }

        return obj as { [key in T]: string };
    }
}
```

The code above works, but the generic T doesn't add much value I think.  If you're hoping to somehow constrain the array passed into the constructor I don't think that can be done this way (?).  So the code below may be better:

```
class DynamicReturnFormat {
    constructor(private keys: string[]) { }

    public returnObject(): { [key: string]: string } {
        const obj: { [key: string]: string } = {};

        for (const key of this.keys) {
            obj[key] = "test";
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rich!  You are correct in that the code you provided works as expected, however I am not happy with either a) repeatedly writing out the type signature as `{ [key in T]: string }` or b) using `{ [key: string]: string }` as I would like the object to have a constrained type signature for ease of debugging.  I have updated the original question to demonstrate the use case.

Comment: @StanStrum you only need to write it once in your example. `const obj = {} as {[P in T]: string};`. The compiler will flow the type.

Comment: The `T` generic does add value here, it determines the properties of the object returned by `returnObject`. Your first solution is the way to go.